# The easiest way to fetch nodes from DOM with specified attributes values

Tags: javascript, html, dom, extjs, selector

This is not a problem, I just ask for the easiest way to implement this.

What I have.

In HTML: list of checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" value="4" />
```

In JavaScript — array of several values: `var aValues = [1, 3];` And I need fetch all checkboxes from DOM with values specified in `aValues`.

How did I do this:

```
var aoNodes = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="1"], input[value="3"]');
```

But maybe anybody know easier (shorter) way to build the query, something like: `input[value="1"|"3"]` or `input[value="1", "3"]`.

Both examples above are incorrect, but I gave them just to be more clear with you.

**UPDATE**

More things to clarify my question:

- jQuery can't be used in my case
- We use ExtJS in our project.

Comment: IMO use a framework like jQuery.  That's one of their main usefulnesses...being able to easily select stuff from DOM

Comment: do you have any experience in jquery?

Comment: Folks, jQuery doesn't offer a shorter form of that selector either. But it does offer a more concise way to filter the result if the OP wants to do it after-the-fact.

Comment: Guys, my mistake — I didn't notice that jQuery cannot be used in this case, but ExtJS. Maybe ExtJS has similar functionality?

Comment: @balkon_smoke: According to the [`DomQuery` docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.DomQuery), no, it doesn't offer a selector that does what you want either. It does offer [`filter`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Array-method-filter) which could be useful if you want to do the filter-after-the-fact approach.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yep, I checked sencha's docs and concluded that JS will be enough without any frameworks or libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `querySelectorAll('input[value="1"], input[value="3"]')` is probably the briefest, even CSS3 doesn't have an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) for "any of these values". (Neither does jQuery.) You can build the big selector from `aValues` fairly easily using `Array#join`:

```
var selector = 'input[type="checkbox"][value="' +
               aValues.join('"], input[type="checkbox"][value="') +
               '"]');
var matches = querySelectorAll(selector);
```

Fairly concise though sadly repeats bits and pieces. You could use a reusable function:

```
function niftyJoin(array, prefix, delim, suffix) {
  return prefix + array.join(suffix + delim + prefix) + suffix;
}
```

Then:

```
var matches = querySelectorAll(niftyJoin(aValues, 'input[type="checkbox"][value="', ',', '"]'));
```

If you don't like the `join` approach, you could get all relevant `input` elements and then filter out the ones whose values are not in the array:

```
var matches, inputs, index, input;
matches = [];
inputs = querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'); // Or perhaps more targeted
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
    input = inputs[index];
    if (aValues.indexOf(parseInt(input.value, 10)) !== -1) {
        matches.push(input);
    }
}
```

That might be slower than building the big selector for `querySelectorAll` since you're filtering in the JavaScript layer rather than the browser's selector engine, but unless you're doing this repeatedly in a tight loop, it's not likely to matter. Also, note that I've relied on `Array#indexOf`, which isn't supported by quite as many browsers as `querySelectorAll` (IE8 has the latter, for instance, but not the former).

Speaking of which: I'm guessing you know that not all browsers support `querySelectorAll` yet, although [**wow** it's getting close](http://caniuse.com/#search=querysel), looks like nearly everything but IE6 and IE7. I assume if you're using it, you know that your target environment will have it.

---

For the jQuery folks: That filtering gets (much) more concise using jQuery:

```
var matches = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function() {
    return $.inArray(parseInt(this.value, 10), aValues);
});
```

Nice and concise. Again, possibly a bit slower than doing it all in `querySelectorAll`, and again unlikely to matter.

---

**Update**: You've said you're using ExtJS on this project. According to the [`DomQuery` docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.DomQuery), it doesn't offer a selector that does what you want either. It does offer [`filter`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Array-method-filter) which could be useful if you want to do the filter-after-the-fact approach, but I frankly think the `join` approach listed at the very top is going to be the most concise and best performing.

Comment: You suggested to me is what I already did. I try to find out more shorter (easier) query. And yep, I understand that not all browsers support `querySelectorAll`, but in my case this has no matter

Comment: @balkon_smoke: No, I go into rather more detail and options than your question did. Your question doesn't mention the `join` trick, which I thought was pretty useful. Other than that, I don't think you have any other options. As I said in the answer, there is no CSS "match any of these" attribute selector.

Comment: thanks for the wide answer, all that I wanted to ask is exactly: is there CSS "match any of these" attribure selector. So, thanks a lot ;)

Comment: @balkon_smoke: Glad that helped. Yeah, buried in there somewhere is the statement that it doesn't (with a link to docs). Too bad, really, but there we are. :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
var checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="checkbox"]' );

checkboxes = [].filter.call( checkboxes, function ( checkbox ) {
    return aValues.indexOf( +checkbox.value ) > -1;
});
```

where `form` is the element that contains all your check-boxes. (You don't want to unnecessarily make a document-level query.)

Note that this uses [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which [may not be available in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility).

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/zF3mu/

Comment: this is cool but isn't shorter ;) thanks, I'll save in mind this way to filter arrays

Comment: As roughly a third of internet users are using browsers that don't have `Array#filter`, probably worth mentioning that...

Comment: @balkon_smoke If you want to filter check-boxes, then `'input[value="1"]'` is not a clean solution, since other types of INPUT elements may sneak in. Therefore, first retrieve all check-boxes, and then filter them based on their values. If you need this functionality repeatedly (more than once), then I recommend a function - `var boxes = getBoxesByValue( aValue );`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I understand this, but I'm sure (in this case) that DOM will not contain any other `input` tags

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That is not an issue at all. The issue are web-pages which *don't* provide ES5-shim to `IE lt 9` via conditional comments. Think about that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder when can we stop putting a disclaimer "Not all browser are ES5 compliant" on every single answer where we use ES5 ?

Comment: @Raynos & Šime: We can stop when all browsers are ES5-compliant. People asking questions should **not** be given answers that will trip them up by seeming to work on one browser only to blow up on another. Just have a standard disclaimer or something you throw on (you have a clipboard organizer thing, right?). It's actively setting traps for the questioner to fail to warn people of this. Note also that the ES5-shim will break naive `for..in` loops. Now, you an I know better, and we try to teach people better, but there are still *lots* of these incorrect `for..in` loops out there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder IE2 doesn't support javascript, should we place a non-javascript disclaimer? I mean really what's the criteria? IE8 has to die before we can use ES5? ES5-shim only breaks for..in on an array that's not filtered. It's not our job to for other people to write code which will work in an ES5 shimmed environment.

Comment: @Raynos: Straw man arguments are inherently poor. ***No,*** IE8 has to die before you can tell people to use features it doesn't have without warning them. Again, **28%** of people use IE8 ([link](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0)) and if you throw in others that don't have ES5 support, we're talking about roughly a third of internet users. We all know web developers tend to use something better. Why the argument? Just warn the person and point them at es5-shim.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I personally think placing a es5 disclaimer on every javascript answer is noise. It's just messy.

Comment: @Raynos: Fine, that's your choice. I disagree (vehemently), I think it's a massive disservice to lay traps for people, so *my* choice is to point out these traps when I see them. I don't expect to convince you, and you're not going to convince me. pax.

Comment: @Raynos: I thought it would be interesting to find out what others think, wanted to give you a head's up so you could weigh in if you like: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118021

Comment: I can't imagine why anyone would *argue* about this. If the question is about JavaScript in the context of a browser (and it is), then knowing which currently-in-use browsers an answer works in is hardly *noise*, @Raynos.

Comment: @Shog9 I was in one of those moods where I like being an ass.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh man. I wanted to open that question on meta. I was looking forward to doing that later today. Grr... `:P`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: LOL Think of it this way, I saved you time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var boxes = [].slice.call(form.elements).filter(function ( element ) {
    return element.type === 'checkbox' && [1,3].indexOf(+element.value) > -1;
});
```

Use `form.elements` to get the inputs of a form. Then filter by type and value.